# Reading from a Socket while keeping the connection open

Tags: haskell, networking

currently I have some code which creates a server and a client for some testing purposes.

Server code

```
import Network.Socket
import Network.Socket.ByteString as NSB
import Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy as NSBL
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.HashMap as HM
import System.IO as IO

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  sock <- socket AF_INET Stream 0
  setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
  bindSocket sock (SockAddrInet (fromInteger 8585) iNADDR_ANY)
  listen sock 100
  servLoop sock

servLoop sock = do
  client = accept sock
  IO.putStrLn "Got a connection"
  h <- SocketToHandle client ReadWriteMode
  hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
  req <- BSL.hGet h 1024
  IO.putStrLn "Got some contents:"
  IO.putStrLn $ show req
```

Client Code

```
import Network.Socket
import Network.BSD
import Control.Monad
import System.IO as IO
import Data.Text as T
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import Data.MessagePack as MP

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  sock <- socket AF_INET Stream 0
  setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
  addr <- liftM hostAddresses $ getHostByName "localhost"
  connect sock $ SockAddrInet (fromInteger 8585) (Prelude.head addr)
  handle <- socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
  replicateM_ 5 $ BSL.hPut handle $ MP.pack ("Hello host" :: Text)
  hFlush handle
  getLine
  replicateM_ 5 $ BSL.hPut handle $ MP.pack ("Hello host" :: Text)
  hFlush handle
  hClose handle
```

The observed behaviour is that the message is not sent until hClose handle is called on the client side. However, I would like to keep the handle open for sending more requests and receiving responses rapidly. Am I going about this the right way? And if so, is there a way to keep the handle open but read and write the socket?

Answer (score 1):

`hGet` keeps trying to read until it has as many bytes as you asked for, namely 1024.  You probably want to use [`hGetNonBlocking`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.2.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:hGetNonBlocking) instead.  Or something like:

```
do
    r1 <- BSL.hGet h 1
    rRest <- BSL.hGetNonBlocking h 1024
    return (r1 BS.append rRest)
```

Comment: I actually ended up using Data.Conduit.Network instead, but thank you for your suggestion!